# Deploying a function fails to clean up build images

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a very simple function to Firebase. However, when I try to deploy it, I get a warning. However, from what I can tell, the function is deployed.

> Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/app-name/us/gcf

With the `--debug` flag:

> Failed docker command with error  HTTP Error: 404, Not Found {"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"context":{"body":{"errors":[{"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"Repository "us.gcr.io" not found"}],"error":{"message":"Not Found"}},"response":{"statusCode":404}},"exit":1,"message":"HTTP Error: 404, Not Found","status":404}

Upon heading to the Cloud Artifacts URL above, there is 1 artifact in there, named `gcf-artifacts` - inside that it looks to be the cache for my function.

Does anyone have any clue on what I need to do to fix this issue? I thought Firebase would handle all of this.

Would this be billing related - if so, where do I look for that?

I've tried deleting the function, including the artifact and then redeploying. Yes, I've enabled the Artifact Registry API. No luck.